# Monitor usage of threadpool from a reactor scheduler with micrometer

Tags: java, scheduler, project-reactor, metrics, micrometer

### Problem

I want to monitor the usage of a thread pool from a specific Scheduler (`BoundedElasticScheduler`). I want to see if the thread pool capacity fits or if it gets to its limit quite often and if there are a lot of waiting tasks.

### Question

I think the **MAX** usage of a threadpool is one of the most important metrics. Is there a metric that I haven't found yet that could be used for it? Or does someone have a hint for me how to observe thread usage in the pool and implement the metric myself?

### Tried so far

1. Using reactors build-in metrics

In `reactor` 3.4.x I found the metric `executor.active`, but it is a gauge and in monitoring tools, this is polled in an interval (e.g. every minute), this is too inaccurate for short tasks that only last some milliseconds in the pool. In `reactor` 3.5 I found a max execution time, but not a max for the active threads amount. The documentations are heavily updated currently because of the 3.5 release, so maybe I miss a metric that could be used for what I need.

2. Using a custom implementation to track usage

I've also tried to implement a `DistributedSummary` around the scheduler, so I'm able to track the **MAX** scheduled tasks per time interval (since `DistributedSummary` uses a `TimeWindowMax` which will show the **MAX** per monitoring interval). But it will only track the scheduling itself, not the real thread usage, for example if you have a Mono which evaluates some `Mono`s and `Flux` inside, which will also use threads from the pool. So it doesn't show me the workload of the pool.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor provides multiple metrics that allow to monitor schedulers:

- `executor_active_threads`, gauge, The approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks
- `executor_pool_core_threads`, gauge,  The core number of threads for the pool
- `executor_pool_max_threads`, gauge,  The maximum allowed number of threads in the pool
- `executor_pool_size_threads`,  gauge, The current number of threads in the pool
- `executor_completed_tasks_total`,  counter, The approximate total number of tasks that have completed execution
- `executor_completed_tasks_total`, counter, The approximate total number of tasks that have completed execution
- `executor_queued_tasks`,  gauge,  The approximate number of tasks that are queued for execution
- `executor_queue_remaining_tasks`, gauge, The number of additional elements that this queue can ideally accept without blocking
- `executor_scheduled_once_total`, counter
- `executor_scheduled_repetitively_total`,  counter
- `executor`, timer

  - `executor_seconds_sum`, counter
  - `executor_seconds_count`, counter
  - `executor_seconds_max`, gauge
- `executor.idle`, timer

  - `executor_idle_seconds_sum`, counter
  - `executor_idle_seconds_count`, counter
  - `executor_idle_seconds_max` , gauge

Internally reactor uses [ExecutorServiceMetrics](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/ExecutorServiceMetrics.java) to instrument Schedulers and add additional tags like `reactor_scheduler_id`.

To monitor number of threads in the reactor schedulers

```
sum(executor_pool_size_threads) by (reactor_scheduler_id)
```

or to monitor max number of threads

```
sum(executor_pool_max_threads) by (reactor_scheduler_id)
```

There is a demo project that could be used to play with reactor metrics and has Grafana dashboards: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-monitoring-demo

Comment: Did you copy those metrics from the documentation? Because the documentation doesn't seem to be correct. With reactor 3.4.x when I check the spring boot actuator, I only get 7. I wanted to have a look into executor_seconds_max but it does not exist. The list of metrics also differ from site to site where you can read about it, like the reacotr docs or the micrometer docs.
`executor_pool_size_threads` is a gauge, so you would have to peek the value just at the right time when there is a max.
`executor_pool_max_threads` is showing the limit of the pool, not the max number of active threads.

Comment: If you are using prometheus, metrics could be discovered using corresponding endpoint from the service itself. In case of Spring Actuator `/actuatur/prometheus`.

Comment: I know, there are still not all of your mentioned metrics, on the other hand, there exists other than you mentioned, so I guess you just copied it from the documentation (which seems not up-to-date)

Comment: These are all metrics related to Schedulers. Internally reactor uses  [ExecutorServiceMetrics](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/ExecutorServiceMetrics.java) to instrument Schedulers and add additional tags like `reactor_scheduler_id`.

Comment: Yea, those are pretty much the same metrics that I see in the actuator and the monitoring. As you can see, there is no `executor_seconds_max`. I also found this in several older docs and questions in SO, I guess this has been removed a while ago. And `executor_active_threads` is a Gauge so there is no chance to get a max when the values are requested in intervals.

Comment: if you look more carefully `executor_seconds_max`gauge  is added by `executor` timer together with `executor_seconds_count` & `executor_seconds_sum` counters https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/928b45fba7d10cbbe724ad41a6d10d72884d25ae/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/internal/TimedScheduledExecutorService.java#L52

To get different metrics for executor threads you would need to wrap executor service somehow that could be tricky to do. Check this thread for details https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15374#issuecomment-499472467.

Comment: I still don't find executor_seconds_max, there is no mention in your link. My actuator shows me the following metrics: `[...,"executor.active","executor.completed","executor.pool.core","executor.pool.max","executor.pool.size","executor.queue.remaining","executor.queued",...]` (... are non-executor metrics, those are really all executor metrics that it shows me) so I'm still wondering where this `seconds_max` is located. I don't find it on their github.

Comment: this is implicit for micrometer timers. I'm not able to troubleshoot  your configuration. try to use demo project I mentioned, check available metrics and see what is different in your project.

Comment: I've tested the demo project. It also does not offer a metric called "executor seconds max" or anything close to that name. If you check actuator/metrics. there are: `["executor","executor.active","executor.completed","executor.idle","executor.pool.core","executor.pool.max","executor.pool.size","executor.queue.remaining","executor.queued","executor.scheduled.once","executor.scheduled.repetitively",...]`. I'm not sure what secondsMax means so maybe it is useless for my case, however, it also does not exist. I don't know why it is mentioned in some documentations.

Comment: To be more specific, just download the mentioned demo project, run it, and check: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics`

Comment: Oh, but in grafana/prometheus, there is such a metric. I guess it is just added by them and has nothing to do with micrometer? Unfortunatly, I'm not using prom/grafana. And I think secondsMax is also not the right metric, I just wondered why it is not in actuator/metrics. There seems to be no useful metric for getting the max-value, since everything there is is a gauge. Gauges are requested on interval, so they are way to inaccurate to be useful.